# i want to create a folder using the md command and append the current date to it

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I want to make a folder using the `md` command and append the current date.

> md = c:\dog %date%

Which does not work.

How do I append the date?

Comment: Do you have a particular standard for the date format that you need? Have you read this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864718/how-to-append-a-date-in-batch-files

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
mkdir "Folder Name %date:~-10,2%"-"%date:~-7,2%"-"%date:~-4,4%"
```

Same command using [Md](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/md) instead of [mkdir](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mkdir).

```
md "Folder Name %date:~-10,2%"-"%date:~-7,2%"-"%date:~-4,4%"
```

Output

```
Folder Name 04-04-2019
```

Edit: Added "-" to "%date:~7,2%"; mkdir and md commands modified, code should now work as expected.

---

Reference

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090/6327676
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/5485853/6327676

Comment: I think you could use `md` as well as `mkdir`

Comment: Yes. You can use `md` as well. Example: `md "Folder Name %date:~-10,2%"-"%date:~7,2%"-"%date:~-4,4%"`

Answer (score 0):

From a Command Line prompt, enter this command:

```
set var=DOG %date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2% && md "%var%"
```

This first creates a system variable 'var' with the value **DOG 20190304**
waits until that's done  ('&&')
then creates a directory named with the contents of 'var'
The "doublequotemarks" are required because of the space between DOG and the date.